# Working with Entities and Repositories in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, jtable

If some of you use Symfony2, you should see what I'm referring to: The entity is basically an object as persisted in the database, and the repository is a class implementing methods to get it, or all, or a subset.

As far as I can see, the JTable class kind of implements a bit of both of these logics, but not quite all of them (for instance, it seems to me that you can't quite query a subset of Elements, nor really rename the table rows in your code to fit another standard). Is there still a way better than constructing these things yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a better way.

Joomla has been developed more in a historic way, whereas both Symfony1 and 2 had a clean slate approach. They are also build for different purposes, Joomla's purpose is much more narrow.

You will see that most major template developer have created their own framework, this shows there is more work to be done at the Joomla end, however judging from the roadmaps, this is not a priority.

I have build a wrapper component to run Symfony1 inside Joomla, but nothing as of yet for Symfony2. Want to work on it together?